# Need to detect face during video call. Using OpenTok or TockBox video calling

Tags: android, face-detection, opentok, tokbox, videochat

I'm using opentok SDK for video calling in app. Need to detect if face is present in front during call. Please help me in this regard.

Opentok library used:

```
implementation 'com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.13.0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect faces you need to use a third party library.
One approach could be using new MLKit library from Google: https://developers.google.com/vision/

MLKit face detection will need to feed it with camera images, when using opentok, the best approach is to build you [own video capturer](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples/blob/master/Custom-Video-Driver/CustomVideoDriverLib/src/main/java/com/example/tokbox/CustomVideoDriverLib/CustomVideoCapturer.java).
That video capturer will capture images from the camera and will also feed them to the library to detect faces.

We wrote a [blog post](https://webrtchacks.com/ml-kit-smile-detection/) about this topic that also had a [sample application](https://github.com/robjperez/SmileDetector). This app is for iOS and used MLKit, the approach is similar to what you would take for Android.